# Fetch value from list in robot framework

Tags: arrays, list, robotframework

I want to fetch the values which are in list I have declared (@{EMAIL_LIST} with 3 values in it)

I am using

```
: FOR    ${a}    IN RANGE    0    3
\    Input Text    id=username    @{EMAIL_LIST}[a]
```

It is giving the error:

> List variable '@{EMAIL_LIST}' used with invalid index 'a'.

Please make me correct, Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You are not forced to use indices in robotframework, you could just iterate over the members: `:FOR   ${a}   IN    @{EMAIL_LIST}`; and as already answered, the variable reference should be in this syntax `${a}`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should use  ${a}  as index instead of 'a'

```
  : FOR    ${a}    IN RANGE    0    3
  \    Input Text    id=username    @{EMAIL_LIST}[${a}]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
: FOR ${a} IN @{EMAIL_LIST} \ Input Text id=username ${a}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I tried fetching the value if we know index number.
`${EMAIL_LIST[index]}`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).